# How to create multiple PointSprites in different states?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, processing, glsles

I'm experimenting with Shaders with Processing 2.0. 
As a simple excersise in understanding Point Shaders a little better,  I have implemented a system whereby in a Sprite class:

1. I set a spritesheet as a uniform sampler2D in the fragment shader. 2048x 2048 (12 x 12 frames of 128 pixels square)
2. I create a point.
3. I setup uv coordinates in the vertex shader for the point.
4. I offset the UV coordinates in the vertex shader by an integer passed in as a uniform variable to select 'frames' in the spritesheet
5. I update the integer (using modulus to loop and) incrementing the UV offset every 5 frames in the application.

This means I can do basic animation sequences from within the vertex shader. I have no idea if this is desirable, but i suspect it would perform better than setting a new uniform sampler2D in the fragment shader every time I want to change frames.

My question is - how can I use this shader across multiple instances? If I want two of the Sprites on screen at the same time each with different values (i.e playing different frames of the animation) how is this achieved without each one having its very own pointShader and therefore its own copy of the uniform Sampler2D in memory?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , this approach is much better then setting new textures every frame.

To draw multiple sprites just use the same program and draw the objects one by one using different uniforms :

1: glUseProgram(yourprogram);

2: ..set texture and uv for the first object

3: ..draw first object

4: ..set new texture (or keep the same texture is the sprites are there)
..set the uv's for the second object

5: ..draw second object and so on

Edit: the program is not bound by the uniforms you set to it , you can always change then and call draw again.

Comment: Thanks - I'm up and running, so simple.